# Key disabled using xmodmap!

Tags: xmodmap

I disabled my key using `xmodmap`. How do I enable it? The command I executed was:

```
`xmodmap -e 'keycode 16='`
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `xmodmap -e 'keycode 16=X'`, where `X` is the key you want to remap?

Comment: How can I type 'x' when x is disabled..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-enable the `7` and the `&` keys, run this:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 16=7 ampersand'
```

Comment: Obviously you wont be able to type 7 , you need to copy and paste the above...